# Ruby adds up two floats to an incorect answer

Tags: ruby

In my rails console, when I add up to floats, i get a suprising result. Why?

```
977.90 + 112.49
=> 1090.3899999999999
```

Isn't the answer 1090.39 ? Why does ruby/rails return the answer it does?

Comment: OK, i googled more.  Floats are inaccurate represnetations of numbers.  fun!

Comment: This article is helpful https://corainchicago.github.io/blog/why-does-ruby-add-numbers-wrong/

Comment: @Amadan: Or `Integer`s. If those numbers represent money, you could do all the calculation in cents. `97790 + 11249 == 109039`, and divide by `100.0` before displaying the results. `(97790 + 11249) / 100.0 #=> 1090.39`.